# Return zero for Some record in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a query inside a stored procedure that count some record inside a table:

```
SELECT
  t_Supporter.supporterID,
  COUNT(t_ticket.ticketID) AS totalTicket
FROM t_Supporter
INNER JOIN t_ticket
  ON t_Supporter.supporterID = t_ticket.supporterID_FK
WHERE (t_Supporter.orgSectionID_FK = @orgID)
GROUP BY t_Supporter.supporterID
```

How can I make my query return **zero** if `t_Supporter.supporterID` have no record in `t_ticket`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `COUNT` to `SUM` with conditional aggregation and your `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT OUTER`

```
SELECT t_Supporter.supporterID, SUM(CASE WHEN t_ticket.ticketID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalTicket
FROM t_Supporter LEFT OUTER JOIN
     t_ticket ON t_Supporter.supporterID = t_ticket.supporterID_FK
WHERE  (t_Supporter.orgSectionID_FK = @orgID)
GROUP BY t_Supporter.supporterID
```